# Can TXT files in Windows hold the same exact text but be of different sizes because one was created a long time before?

Tags: windows-explorer, encoding, text-formatting

I divided one big txt ~500 KB file into 6 files (5 additional) by cut and paste, the new files' total size is much smaller than the original file.

Can this be because of new encoding ways in Windows 10 than when I created the file ~9 years ago?

When I created the first original file ~9 years ago I chose Unicode but now it was automatic.

Answer (score 1):

I take "it was automatic" to mean that you used for the new file
the default encoding format for notepad or some other text editor.

The default text encoding is ANSI, which uses one byte per character.
As the old encoding was Unicode, which may use more than one byte per
character, this may explain the size difference.

You should check the result, to ensure that no data was lost during
the copy-paste, as for example by non-ANSI characters being converted
by truncation, or converted to ANSI characters that are only similar.

Comment: But I have special characters in all, does that make the encoding in Notepad on Windows 10 automatically Unicode to be able to encode them correctly?

Comment: Special characters may not convert correctly to ANSI. The fact that the new file is much smaller should be taken as a large warning sign. You could always repeat the copy-paste to files of the same encoding as the source, or use a program to split the file into chunks with no conversion.

Comment: See [this](https://alternativeto.net/software/splitfile/) for splitting programs.

Comment: Thanks for the link and I hope others find it useful, I just did my 5 txt files manually and checked them with a C# code and they have the exact same number of entries (quotations) as the original.

Answer (score 1):

Check the encoding by opening each file in **Notepad** and then launching the `Save As` dialog. The `Encoding` selector will be set to whatever encoding was used when the file was saved:

[image]

If it's not encoding, check for Alternate Data Streams in the larger file:

1. Open a `Command Propmpt` to the directory containing the file in question.
2. A `dir /R` command will reveal any files with Alternate Data Streams:

(Fies with ADS are most commonly found in the `Downloads` direcgtory, where htey serve as ZoneIdentifiers)

```
C:\Users\keith\Downloads>dir /AA /R
 Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is F057-590D

 Directory of C:\Users\keith\Downloads

10/02/2015  09:20 PM         1,730,272 ActiveSetupN.exe
05/12/2019  11:49 AM             8,312 Add_Settings_to_desktop_context_menu.reg
                                   280 Add_Settings_to_desktop_context_menu.reg:Zone.Identifier:$DATA
03/27/2018  10:29 PM         1,747,504 adksetup.exe
02/07/2018  09:18 PM            55,296 advchange.exe

...

06/03/2019  03:32 PM           165,184 amtrak-vacations-network-map-2019.jpg
                                   245 amtrak-vacations-network-map-2019.jpg:Zone.Identifier:$DATA

...

              92 File(s)  2,139,170,500 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  610,151,268,352 bytes free
```

Answer (score 1):

There are MANY "Unicode" character encodings. In Windows-speak, "Unicode" has usually meant UTF-16LE, so that English text would occupy 2 bytes per character. The default encoding in Notepad is now UTF-8, which would halve
the size of the same standard English text, including the "usual" special characters.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility aside from what has been posted already.

There are 2 filesizes. The actual filesize, and the size on disk. If a file is fragmented a lot, it can be that the filesize increases because parts can occupy part of a cluster, but the entire clusters are counted.

So it is possible that a file is 300kb but 500kb on disk. Windows tends to show the filesize that is largest.

You can verify this by right-clicking the file in explorer and choose properties. There you see both the filesize of the file and the filesize on disk.

[image]